# How can money have a value?

Tags: inflation, money

The value of money can be the value to produce it. It costs, say, 1, to produce 10 000 000, in the mean (coins and paper, though digital money costs virtually nothing). This is called the extrinsic value. But I'm not sure I understand what determines its intrinsic value. I understand the extrinsic and intrinsic value of a diamond (though this value can be zero for people not interested in money or the rarity of the diamond). It costs a certain amount to produce one and it is rare (I don't think its value is determined by its shiny appearance). But what about the intrinsic value of money?
In the Weimar Republic, the intrinsic value of the German mark spiraled down, with the consequence that you had to pay more and more for the mark. Notes of 100 000 000 000  mark were commonly used. Of course, you can turn 100 000 000 000 into a 1, so that a piece of bread now costs 1 mark. But this means that virtually all people possessing marks would be a billionaire. Or the state could simply declare the old money to be invalid (like the pre-euro money is invalid now, though the reason to make the pre-euro money invalid is different).
Money can be produced in larger and larger amounts (or zeros could be added to banknotes) but that will devaluate its worth just more. If there is twice as much its intrinsic value will be halved (though the people who produce it can be crooks who take all the money for themselves). Now there is trust involved but I'm not sure what that means. Is it that people didn't trust the old German mark that it devaluated? Why should your trust become less? Because of a bad economy?
So what determines the value of money? Any enlightenment is welcome!

Comment: Have a look on the following post https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37922/why-does-fiat-money-have-value/37924#37924 that may answer your question.

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt That's an interesting question. It relates fiat money to taxes. So the value of fiat money (the money as coins and notes or bitcoins only) is influenced by taxes. If you have to pay high taxes on the money its value will obviously decrease (you are left with less of it after the tax payment, unless you do not tell anything to the state that taxes). but this has nothing to do with the intrinsic value (apart from the fact that you have to pay tax when you get it).  well, maybe its intrinsic value will be a bit less (who wants to pay tax when you acquire it?).

Comment: @HolgerI.Meinhardt But apert from taxes (do you have to pay this too if you change the money into other currencies?), what determines the intrinsic value? I mean money that is not backed up by gold. Is its value just determined by the products that a country produces?

Comment: The point is not about taxing or not taxing, it is about  how to impose a positive or negative marginal utility on a good to create or destroy a market. And by taxes one can create a positive marginal utility on fiat money to the user. The German Mark becomes almost worthless during the hyper-inflation to the users, because it has almost no utility for the consumer. Thus, if a good has a positive marginal utility to someone, it has a positve intrinsic value even though its extrinsic value is zero.